# Проблема - файл закрывается, если нажать Enter 2 раза в косольной программе Python

Tags: python

```
v = open(u"/storage/emulated/0/PyTycoon/Variables.txt","w")
#Variables
L = 1
k = 0
s1 = 5
money = 0
#Functions
def shops(k):
    k = s1 * 2
    return(k)
#Commands
while True:
    z = input()
    if z == ".":
        money = money + L
    elif z == "balance" or z == "b":
        print(f"balance: {money}")
    elif z == "shop" or z == "sh":
        print(f"------Shop------\nshovel(+5) - {s1}$")
    elif z == "buy shovel" and money >= s1:
        money = money - s1
        L = L + 5
        s1 = shops(k)
        print(f"balance: {money}")
    elif z == "save" or "s":
        v.write(str((money)))
        v.close()
```

Проблема:

Файл закрывается, если нажать Enter 2 раза. Как сделать, чтобы его можно было нажимать бесконечно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

потому что второй раз выполняется вот такое условие, когда на входе ничего нет

```
elif z == "save" or "s":
```

да и неправильно оно составлено, замените на

```
elif z in ("save", "s"):
```

А у вас по сути:

```
if "s":
    print("всегда")
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на  Stack Overflow на русском! [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)